# Having trouble hiding my dialog title bar while keeping its close button

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dialog, modal-dialog, titlebar

I’m using JQuery 1.12.  I want to create a dialog with no title bar, but keep the close button in the upper right.  I have tried this for CSS

```
#myModal .ui-dialog-titlebar {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 0px none;
}
```

and here’s my JS …

```
  $(function() {
        $(".searchResultsDetailRow").click(function() {
          var opt;
          opt = {
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            width: 'auto',
            focus: function() {
              return $(this).dialog('option', 'width', $('#myModal').width() + 50);
            }
          };
          $("#myModal").dialog(opt);
          $("#myModal").dialog("open");

    });
  });
```

but still the title bar appears.  How do I make it disappear?  This is my Fiddle — https://jsfiddle.net/adaor26p/6/ .

Comment: Did you want to remove or just change background color and border style . ? on your post you said you want to create a dialog with no title bar but you tried just change background color and border with your css ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your solution is not working is that the dialog is not wrapped in an element with an `id` of `myModal`. Try this:

```
div[aria-describedby="myModal"] .ui-dialog-titlebar {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 0px none;
}
```